# My Android pushes are delivered and displayed at system tray only when app is running

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I registered my Android app for GCM with Aurban Airship SDK and was able to receive some pushes. The issue is that I'm receiving them only when the app is active (or even when it is backgrounded).
Once I terminate the app - incoming pushes aren't displayed at the system tray neither at the notification center.

Should I have any specific "push handling logic" beyond Airship SDK?
Any suggestions?

Comment: I am running into this issue too. Have you ever figured this out?